# Как записать в Excel в уже имеющийся файл?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Занимаюсь парсингом и возникла проблема с записью в Excel в уже имеющийся файл.
Нашел вот такое вот решение:

```
def append_df_to_excel(filename, df, sheet_name='Sheet1', startrow=None,
                   truncate_sheet=False, 
                   **to_excel_kwargs):
"""
Append a DataFrame [df] to existing Excel file [filename]
into [sheet_name] Sheet.
If [filename] doesn't exist, then this function will create it.

Parameters:
  filename : File path or existing ExcelWriter
             (Example: '/path/to/file.xlsx')
  df : dataframe to save to workbook
  sheet_name : Name of sheet which will contain DataFrame.
               (default: 'Sheet1')
  startrow : upper left cell row to dump data frame.
             Per default (startrow=None) calculate the last row
             in the existing DF and write to the next row...
  truncate_sheet : truncate (remove and recreate) [sheet_name]
                   before writing DataFrame to Excel file
  to_excel_kwargs : arguments which will be passed to 'DataFrame.to_excel()'
                    [can be dictionary]

Returns: None
"""
from openpyxl import load_workbook

import pandas as pd

# ignore [engine] parameter if it was passed
if 'engine' in to_excel_kwargs:
    to_excel_kwargs.pop('engine')

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='openpyxl')

# Python 2.x: define [FileNotFoundError] exception if it doesn't exist 
try:
    FileNotFoundError
except NameError:
    FileNotFoundError = IOError


try:
    # try to open an existing workbook
    writer.book = load_workbook(filename)

    # get the last row in the existing Excel sheet
    # if it was not specified explicitly
    if startrow is None and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
        startrow = writer.book[sheet_name].max_row

    # truncate sheet
    if truncate_sheet and sheet_name in writer.book.sheetnames:
        # index of [sheet_name] sheet
        idx = writer.book.sheetnames.index(sheet_name)
        # remove [sheet_name]
        writer.book.remove(writer.book.worksheets[idx])
        # create an empty sheet [sheet_name] using old index
        writer.book.create_sheet(sheet_name, idx)

    # copy existing sheets
    writer.sheets = {ws.title:ws for ws in writer.book.worksheets}
except FileNotFoundError:
    # file does not exist yet, we will create it
    pass

if startrow is None:
    startrow = 0

# write out the new sheet
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, startrow=startrow, **to_excel_kwargs)

# save the workbook
writer.save()
```

Но при вызове данной функции возникает ошибка:

> zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file

Запуск самой функции в моём коде:

```
append_df_to_excel("file.xlsx", get_content(driver), startrow=None, header=None)
```

Функция get_content(driver):

```
def get_content(driver):
data = {}
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Name", "Car", "Carrier", "Mail", "Info"])
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 100)
data["Name"] = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="Card Card_service_yandex RouteInfoCard"]/ul[@class="List"][3]/li[2]/div[2]'))).text
data["Car"] = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="Card Card_service_yandex RouteInfoCard"]/ul[@class="List"][3]/li[3]/div[2]'))).text
data["Carrier"] = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="Card Card_service_yandex RouteInfoCard"]/ul[@class="List"][3]/li[4]/div[2]'))).text
data["Mail"] = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="Card Card_service_yandex RouteInfoCard"]/ul[@class="List"][4]/li[2]/div[2]'))).text
data["Info"] = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='RouteInfoCard__controls']/a[2]"))).get_attribute('href')
df = df.append(data, ignore_index=True)
return df
```

Большую часть решений уже попробовал, ничего не помогло. Скорее всего, я что-то неправильно делал.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Похоже ваш `"file.xlsx"` уже сломан и не является валидным Excel файлом.

Для того, чтобы проверить "валидность" Excel файла - попробуйте открыть файл в Excel.

Попробуйте создать новый, заведомо рабочий Excel файл и опять воспользоваться [прекрасной функцией `append_df_to_excel ()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38075046).

;)

---

**UPD:** попытка воспроизведения:

```
In [28]: filename = "taxi.xlsx"

In [29]: df = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=0)

In [30]: df
Out[30]:
          Name                   Car       Carrier             Mail Info
0  М*****в Бек  Жёлтый Skoda Octavia  ООО "ТК-АВИ"  m******@mail.ru    -

In [31]: append_df_to_excel(filename, df, startrow=None, header=None)

In [32]: df2 = pd.read_excel(filename, index_col=0)

In [33]: df2
Out[33]:
          Name                   Car       Carrier             Mail Info
0  М*****в Бек  Жёлтый Skoda Octavia  ООО "ТК-АВИ"  m******@mail.ru    -
0  М*****в Бек  Жёлтый Skoda Octavia  ООО "ТК-АВИ"  m******@mail.ru    -
```

все замечательно отработало - фрейм с одной строкой добавился к существующему Excel файлу и в итоге в файле - две одинаковых строки.

PS версии библиотек:

```
In [34]: pd.show_versions()

INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
python           : 3.7.7.final.0
python-bits      : 64
OS               : Darwin
LOCALE           : None.UTF-8

pandas           : 1.1.1
numpy            : 1.19.1
xlsxwriter       : 1.3.3
openpyxl         : 3.0.5
xlrd             : 1.2.0
xlwt             : 1.3.0
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119329/discussion-between-maxu-and-koplik).

Comment: добрый день. Очень благодарен за помощь, установил версии библиотек такие же как у вас и все заработало отлично

Comment: @Koplik, был рад помочь)